# Azure Machine Learning Workbench hangs while creating new project

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying Azure Machine Learning Services following this tutorial ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/quickstart-installation)). After successfully creating the Azure Machine Learning services accounts, I successfully installed the Workbench on my Windows 10 Laptop (Behind Proxy; Proxy has been configured at the WorkBench). Next, I was trying to create project following this section ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/quickstart-installation#create-a-project-in-workbench)). Once I click on the Create button, it goes to "Creating" state and stays there for ever. The errors displayed at Errors.log is the following. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
[2018-07-09 09:47:08.437] [ERROR] HttpService - {"event":"HttpService","task":"Failed","data":{"url":"http://localhost:54240/projects/v1.0/create/template","status":500,"statusText":"INKApi Error","jsonError":null,"requestId":null,"sessionType":"Workbench"},"sid":"365395c0-832b-11e8-b4ce-e5d7046c6143"}

[2018-07-09 09:47:08.960] [ERROR] CreateProjectForm - {"event":"CreateProject","task":"Error","data":{"_body":null,"status":500,"ok":false,"statusText":"INKApi Error","headers":{"Date":["Mon"," 09 Jul 2018 04:17:06 GMT"],"Via":["1.1 localhost.localdomain"],"Proxy-Connection":["close"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Content-Type":["text/html"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost:54240/projects/v1.0/create/template"},"sid":"365395c0-832b-11e8-b4ce-e5d7046c6143"}

[2018-07-09 09:47:08.963] [FATAL] ExceptionLogger - {"event":"exception","task":"","data":{"message":"Cannot read property 'error' of null","name":"TypeError","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null\n    at SafeSubscriber._error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:61476:58)\n    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:212279:20)\n    at SafeSubscriber.error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:212241:30)\n    at Subscriber._error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:212172:30)\n    at Subscriber.error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:212146:22)\n    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:210968:30)\n    at InnerSubscriber._error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:211072:25)\n    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:212146:22)\n    at DeferSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:210968:30)\n    at InnerSubscriber._error (file:///C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/AmlWorkbench/resources/app.asar/src/App/main.bundle.js:211072:25)"},"sid":"365395c0-832b-11e8-b4ce-e5d7046c6143"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because of the Proxy (although I have configured the Proxy on the Workbench). When I am connected to internet directly, everything works fine (Able to create project, train, compare models etc). However the Workbench should return meaningful error instead of hanging or simply waiting while creating the project.